# Data posted from Html editor not works in Chrome

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html-editor, cleditor

I am using Html Editor in MVC3 view to store article info as:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
     {
      ...
      @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.OtherInformation, new { @id = "OtherInformation" })
      ...
     }
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery.cleditor.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.cleditor.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.cleditor.xhtml.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#OtherInformation").cleditor();
</script>
```

and in controller I have written the code to save article as:

```
       [ValidateInput(false)]
       [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Article article)
        {            

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                article.EntryDate = DateTime.Now;
                new ArticleService().SaveOrUpdateArticle(article);
                return RedirectToAction("ArticleIndex");
            }

            return View(article);
        }
```

**This all works fine in IE,but when I run the same in Chrome then "OtherInformation" always go Null.**

Comment: `"OtherInformation" always go Null` !?, can you elaborate more on what is not working in chrome

Comment: also you should say in your question that you are using [CLEditor](http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/)

Comment: OtherInformation is one field input value in model Article for which i used the Textarea as shown in code: @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.OtherInformation, new { @id = "OtherInformation" })

Comment: pls try commenting `$("#OtherInformation").cleditor();` and check if still the error persist, I am not sure but it may be because Chrome just got an update recently, still not sure just guessing :)

Comment: and i am using this text area as Html editor by using javascript:  
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#OtherInformation").cleditor();.....Now when user enter data for otherInformation in IE and post the data.it works fine and data will get save.but in Chrome the user enetr data and post it...the value set in html editor become null after post ....

Comment: yea i do think so...because this functionality is working properly in chrome just a month ago...now i m getting the prob

Comment: chrome just got an update yesterday ! check [this](http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.in/)

Comment: When I commented $("#OtherInformation").cleditor();...HTML Editor Becomes a simple Text Area.....Which works....But I want HTML Editor...thats why I included it.....Any Other Suggestion....

Comment: dats what I was thinking, your plugin is not working with the latest version of chrome, this maybe the problm, in which case you can report [here](http://code.google.com/p/cleditor/issues/entry)

Comment: Thank u....I have posted the issue .....

Answer (score 0):

This problem was fixed in version 1.4.0.